# Is the repo class thread safety for concurrent requests? - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring boot with jetty embedded web server for one Web application.
I want to be 100% sure that the repo class is thread safety.

The repo class

```
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class RegistrationGroupRepositoryImpl implements RegistrationGroupRepository {

  private RegistrationGroup rg = null;
  Integer sLastregistrationTypeID = 0;
  private UserAccountRegistration uar = null;
  private List<RegistrationGroup> registrationGroup = new ArrayList<>();

  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


  @Autowired
  public RegistrationGroupRepositoryImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
     this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  public List<RegistrationGroup> getRegistrationGroups(Integer regId) {
    // Some logic here which is stored in stored in the instance variables and registrationGroup is returned from the method

   return this.registrationGroup;
  }
```

And the Service class which invoke the getRegistrationGroups method from the repo.

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

  @Autowired
  private Provider<RegistrationGroupRepository> registrationGroupRepository;

  public List<RegistrationGroup> getRegistrationGroup() {
     return registrationGroupRepository.getRegistrationGroups(1);
  }

}
```

Can I have race condition situation if two or more request execute the getRegistrationGroups(1) method? 
I guess I'm on the safety side because I'm using Method injection (Provider) with prototype bean, and every time I'm getting new instance from the invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, making your Bean a *prototype* Bean doesn't ensure an instance is created for every method invocation (or every usage, whatever).

In your case you're okay on that point, thanks to the `Provider` usage.
I noticed however that you're accessing the `getRegistrationGroups` directly.

```
return registrationGroupRepository.getRegistrationGroups(1);
```

How can this code compile? You should call `get()` on the `Provider` instance.

```
return registrationGroupRepository.get().getRegistrationGroups(1);
```

Answering your question, you should be good to go with this code. I don't like the fact that you're maintaining some sort of state inside `RegistrationGroupRepositoryImpl`, but that's your choice.

I always prefer having all my fields as `final`. If one of them requires me to remove the `final` modifier, there is something wrong with the design.

Comment: I just modified the class in the editor here and I forgot to put .get().  Thank you a lot for your precision. I know that this code is no OK, but I don't have time to refactor it, because there is so much logic implemented there..

Comment: @Rostislav I understand. Sometimes as developers we have to accept tradeoffs, even if we don't like the result.